# Create two datasets by equally dividing rows based on postal codes in R

Tags: r, random, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a dataset with customer codes, customer name, and postal codes. The dataset has 149130 rows. I want to equally split it into two datasets (each of 74565 rows) and export in excel. However I want to make sure that if there are two customers for one postal code - one goes to dataset1 and the other goes to dataset2. The rest can be a random selection of customers. I am new to r and have tried various train/test and sample codes - however I haven't been able to achieve the result needed.

To summarize - I am trying to create 2 random samples out of the dataframe but want to make sure that if there are more than 2 customers under a certain postal code - they should be equally split between the two samples.

sample data -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKSoA.png)
TIA

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data, e.g. `dput(head(my_data))`.

Comment: this could be useful https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/splitstackshape/versions/1.4.8/topics/stratified

Comment: @markhogue image attached. TIA

Comment: @NKHH, users can't copy the data from the image. Please paste the output in the question block.

Comment: I made some passable bogus data in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make some reproducible data.

```r
set.seed(2020)
zipcode <- sample.int(10000:99999, size = 149130, replace = TRUE)
zipcode <- stringr::str_pad(as.character(zipcode), width = 5, pad = "0")
custname <- sample(letters, size = 149130, replace = TRUE)
customers <- data.frame(zipcode = zipcode, custname = custname)
str(customers)
#> 'data.frame':    149130 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ zipcode : chr  "09628" "09452" "07767" "08920" ...
#>  $ custname: chr  "k" "y" "n" "a" ...
```

Then let's let `caret` do all the hard work.  It it add a column that you can then use to split one dataframe into 2.  I `head` the results but a human inspection is you got as close to 50/50 as possible

```r
customers$whichsample <- caret::createFolds(factor(customers$zipcode), 
                                                   k = 2, 
                                                   list = FALSE )

head(table(customers$zipcode, customers$whichsample))
#>        
#>          1  2
#>   00001  8  7
#>   00002  4  5
#>   00003  8  7
#>   00004  7  6
#>   00005  7  8
#>   00006 11 11
```

Subsequent ask to show how to divide into two separate dataframes.  Safe and slow `tidy` method assuming you want `csample1` and `csample2`

```r
csample1 <- customers %>% filter(whichsample == 1)
csample2 <- customers %>% filter(whichsample == 2)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. That is a good start for me. How can I create the two data frames from this, where I will have the exact list of customer codes in the two samples?

Comment: YW, added to answer, please mark it correct if it meets your needs

Answer (score 0):

My general approach would be:

- Create a extra dataset with unique postal codes from the starting dataset
- Shuffle it randomly if needed
- split that into two halfes
- right join the starting dataset with one half on the postal code to get the first sample and with the other half to get the second sample